# Authcache: Getting user_link to work in template.php

Tags: 7, routes

**Problem**

I'm trying to set-up an Authcache customised menu.

The first way of doing it would be to create 3 menus, one for each of my roles and one for anon then create a custom tpl.php for each using the `user_link` and `user_name` variables.

(These variables are provided by the user example module in authcache to all templates.)

Block logic would then give the correct user the correct menu.

It seems a little clumsy.

Is it possible to grab the links inside template.php and use `user_link` and `user_name` variables there because I can't find a function which has the links available.

Or how has anyone else solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of a preprocess hook, yes:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_foo(&$vars) {
  $user_link = $vars['user_link'];
}
```

Outside of that context I guess you could invoke `authcache_usercookie_preprocess()` manually:

```
$vars = array('user' => $GLOBALS['user']);
authcache_usercookie_preprocess($vars, NULL);
$user_link = $vars['user_link'];
```

Comment: Cheers Clive. I'd been trying to use MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_tree which I couldn't get to work for some reason.

Comment: Hmm so in my arrogance I may have prematurely posted my answer. I thought changing the href in the MYTHEME_preprocess_page would change the rendered HTML, but it doesn't. I thought preprocess_page happened before theming? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes I was, I'd been outputting the menu as a block, as opposed to a variable from page.tpl.php. Apparently 4 months I couldn't get enough of blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is my solution.

Menu's are themed in `MYTHEME_preprocess_page`, the menu data is also still structured here unlike in `MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_tree`.

I enabled the memcached example module, this enables the variables `user_link` and `user_name` in the preprocess. Then I created a third variable `user_account` just copying from the other two and altered the cookie so it stores `uid` not `name`.

This is because I wanted the "My Account" link to link to "user/x/edit" and I didn't need the name.

I then added the following chunk to my page preprocess.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page (&$vars) {
  $user_account = $vars['user_account'];
    if (array_key_exists('menu-xxxx', $vars['secondary_menu'])) { 
      $vars['secondary_menu']['menu-xxxx']['href'] = $user_account; 
    }
```

The secondary menu in this case is my user menu and My Account is always labelled menu-xxxx in the array. (xxxx will be numbers).